# Manually laravel 5 package install in project

Tags: php, laravel

I have install a new **laravel 5** project. In my other project i have several packages. I want to install my expected packages from copying package from vendor folder and paste into my new project. I want to do that because composer is really slow to install new package from online.

Comment: install via composer is highly recommended instead of copying. I've tried copy one of vendor package to my current project, the package can't working properly and sometimes the project didn't recognize it.

Comment: If you do that, once you do a `update composer`, these packages will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't install manually because it will be a lot of task then. e.g when Laravel installs through composer it has some scripts which runs at different steps of install it copies `.env` file it generates `key` etc. You can see https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json#L31 & https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-types. Now you can copy paste of your full previous code & remove controllers, models, packages from composer.json. But if you manually install it won't be a wise decision.

Answer (score 0):

For composer You can use https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo

It gives you the ability to install packages and dependencies in parallel mode. This gives a huge boost during installing projects/packages.